# jQuery.validator.addMethod always returning true in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate if a user already exists or not. The error output of username is always "This username is already taken.".

**jQuery validation:**

All validation errors work except uniqueUsername (required, minlength, maxlength, lettersonly are working fine).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter only letters");


$.validator.addMethod("uniqueUsername", function(value, element) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "<?php echo base_url();?>user/check_user",
        data : "username=" + value,
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(msg) {
            if (msg == 'true') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
}, "This username is already taken.");

$("#form").validate({
    rules : {
        username : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 3,
            maxlength : 25,
            lettersonly : true,
            uniqueUsername : true
        },
    },

    messages : {

        username : {
            required : "Username is required.",
        },
    },

    errorElement : "span",
    errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent());
    }
});
```

**controllers/user.php:**

The function check_user() sends the username in an array to my model users. I have tested this function and it works as it should be.

```
public function check_user() {
    $this -> load -> model('users');
    $user = array('username' => $this -> input -> post('username'));
    if ($this -> users -> is_user_username($user)) {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

**models/users.php**

This function takes the array and checks if this username already exists in my database, if it does -> true, else -> false.

```
public function is_user_username($user) {
    $this -> db -> where('username', $user['username']);
    $query = $this -> db -> get('users');
    if ($query -> num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Quote OP**:
> "`models/users.php` - This function takes the array and checks if this **username already exists** in my database, **if it does -> true**, else -> false."

So then the logic of your `uniqueUsername` method is backwards:

```
success : function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'true') { // <-- if username exists
        return true;     // <-- this means 'passed- no error'
    } else {
        return false;    // <-- since you did not get a match, it shows error
    }
}
```

**A `return false` within the custom validation method is what triggers the error message.**

In other words, `return false` ==> *"validation failed, show the error message"*

Your PHP logic, as per your own description of the the PHP function, is returning `false` to the `success` `msg`, which fails your conditional logic, so then gives a `return false`, which is what's triggering the error message.

Try this instead...

```
success : function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'true') { // <-- if username exists
        return false;    // <-- this means 'failed- show message'  
    } else {
        return true;     // <-- this means 'passed- no error'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use the remote method?  there are a couple of examples [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote)

That way you don't have to write your own method, you can just specify the rules like so.  Your check_user page will be passed the contents of the username field and should return just the words true or false

```
rules : {
 username : {
  required : true,
  minlength : 3,
  maxlength : 25,
  lettersonly : true,
  remote: "<?php echo base_url();?>user/check_user"
 },
},
```